# how to close autocomplete dropdown if jqgrid edit form is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid, jquery-ui-autocomplete

jqgrid edit for in form editing mode contains jquery-ui autocomplete.
If its autocomplete dropdown is opened and edit form is closed by pressing cross in upper right corner, 
autocomplete dropdown remains open. how to force it to be closed if edit form is closed by close button ?

Edit form is defined using

```
$grid.jqGrid("navGrid", "#grid_toppager", { 
            search:  true,
            del: true,
            add: true,
            view: true,
            refresh: true, 
            edit: true
          }, 

{ 
     url: '/erp/Grid/Edit?_entity=Klient',
            closeAfterEdit: true,
   } );
```

autocomplete is created using

```
input.autocomplete({
    source: '/Grid/GetLookupList',
    position: { collision: 'flip flip' },
}   );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can close the autocompletes on closing the dialog in jqgrid, as

```
$grid.jqGrid("navGrid", "#grid_toppager", { 
        search:  true,
        del: true,
        add: true,
        view: true,
        refresh: true, 
        edit: true
      }, 
      { 
        url: '/erp/Grid/Edit?_entity=Klient',
        closeAfterEdit: true,
        onClose: function(){ input.autocomplete("close"); }
      });
```

Hope this helps.